# Duck typing - what about when you need a concrete type?

Tags: dynamic-languages, duck-typing

Say you are doing a calculator in a dynamic language (Python etc...) and you have an add method.

```
def Add(x, y)
    print x + y
```

Now if you were to pass in anything but a number that would be wrong, so you need some datatype checking.

Is Duck Typing about objects as opposed to parameters like the above example?

Could anyone explain further?

**Edit**

By objects I mean:

```
Person.Quack()
Duck.Quack()
```

With no care about what gets passed into methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duck typing is about not caring what the objects you're working with are as long as they support the necessary operations.  So if + is string concatenation then passing strings to Add would be fine.  If dates support the + operation then passing dates would be fine as well.

Comment: +1 The example Add method will work nicely for strings.  With respect to `+`, many many types will work.

Comment: This is what I read/understood however what happens when you don't want them to use a date. In the case of a calculator you'd be forced to check data types. Thus voiding Duck Typing.

Comment: @Dockers: Why check data types?  Why can't the calculator work with dates and strings?

Comment: Because its meant to be a numeric calculator. Imagine the spec was to produce a simple calculator and if the user entered anything other than digits 0 - 9 they get a friendly error message.

Comment: Then you need to validate the input before it gets to this method.